# Search result permalink

Tags: permalinks, search

how to make permalink available for search result page

/?s=one+two+ok to /search/one-two-ok/

thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That kind of search request should already work(query it directly in your address bar), the component you're missing is redirecting the non-pretty search requests..

For doing the redirect, you should find the following plugin still works..
http://txfx.net/wordpress-plugins/nice-search/

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

i found this

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)?$ /index.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and in form

```
<form action=";/index.php" method="get" onsubmit="location.href='/search/' + encodeURIComponent(this.s.value).replace(/%20/g, '+'); return false;">
```

source : [seo-wordpress-search-with-permalink-structure/](http://www.h4x3d.com/seo-wordpress-search-with-permalink-structure/)

if you have a better solution i want it